# How can I improve this code?

Tags: php, mysql

Could I somehow only use only 1 sql query for this?

showthread.php

```
// Get Topic subject etc
$threadID = isset($_GET['threadID']) ? intval($_GET['threadID']) : 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = $threadID");

// Fetch rows
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$subject = htmlspecialchars($row['subject']);

echo '<h2>'.$subject.'</h2>';


// Get posts that belong to this topic!
$posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id WHERE posts.topic_id = $threadID");

// posts.....
while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts)) {
    echo '<br>'.$post['message'].'';
}
```

Comment: This might be better-suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you don't get a good response here, you should try posting this on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Beside selecting specific columns instead of doing `SELECT *`, and removing that nasty, useless `.''` in your loop, there aren't many things to comment.

Comment: If you want a single query why don't you just join with the topics table too?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you should be able to get all the information you need from something like this? (Plus or minus any missing columns)

```
SELECT topics.subject, posts.message
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id
INNER JOIN topics ON topics.id = posts.topic_id
WHERE posts.topic_id = $threadID
```

Comment: +1 specifying the columns you want instead of "select *" is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli
Use real_escape_string
Use Prepared statement or PDO

Comment: In this case, real_escape_string wouldn't really be terribly beneficial -- he's casting to a number first.

Comment: @cwallenpoole, indeed true in this case. But these are still all good suggestions on how to *improve the code*. +1